# Table view with sections to use single array

Tags: swift

I have a table with some items and sections for those items. Both the items and sections are hard-coded and I'm having a little trouble understanding how I could rather have everything loaded from one array rather than two.

Here is my code:

```
 import UIKit

class Beta: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


    let section = ["Fruits", "Vegetables"]
    let items = [["Apple", "Banana"], ["Carrots", "Broccoli"]]






    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true




    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning(){
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return self.items[section].count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return self.section.count
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{
        return self.section[section]
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        //MARK: -Checkmark and save support.
        cell.accessoryType = cell.isSelected ? .checkmark : .none
        cell.selectionStyle = .none // to prevent cells from being "highlighted"



        return cell
    }









}





}
```

I used code that I could find online and the only working code I could find had the sections and items seperate in two arrays.

How can I make it read everything off of this one array?

```
var Food:NSDictionary = [
        //:Section Title : Items
        "Fruits" : ["Apple","Banana"],
        "Vegetables" : ["Carrots","Broccoli"]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
struct Section {
 var name: String!
 var items: [String]!
 init(name: String, items: [String]) {
    self.name = name
    self.items = items
 }
}


import UIKit

class Beta: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
var sections = [Section]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 56.0
    self.tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tblView.tableFooterView = UIView()
     // Initialize the sections array
    sections = [
        Section(name: "Fruits", items: ["Apple", "Banana"]),
        Section(name: "Vegetables", items: ["Carrots", "Broccoli"]),
    ]
 }

 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
 }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    // For section 1, the total count is items count plus the number of headers
    var count = sections.count

    for section in sections {
        count += section.items.count
    }

    return count
   }

 // Add two prototype cell in your storyboard and give identifier "header" for header cell and "cell" for another one. 

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell: UITableViewCell?
    // Calculate the real section index and row index
    let section = getSectionIndex(row: indexPath.row)
    let row = getRowIndex(row: indexPath.row)

        if row == 0 {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "header")! as UITableViewCell
        headerCell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        headerCell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blue
        headerCell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        headerCell.textLabel?.text = sections[section].name
        headerCell.selectionStyle = .none
        return headerCell
    } else {
            if cell == nil {
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
            }
        cell?.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell?.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        cell?.selectionStyle = .none
        cell?.textLabel?.text = sections[section].items[row - 1]
        }
        return cell!
    }

//
// MARK: - Helper Functions
//
func getSectionIndex(row: NSInteger) -> Int {
    let indices = getHeaderIndices()

    for i in 0..<indices.count {
        if i == indices.count - 1 || row < indices[i + 1] {
            return i
        }
    }

    return -1
}

func getRowIndex(row: NSInteger) -> Int {
    var index = row
    let indices = getHeaderIndices()

    for i in 0..<indices.count {
        if i == indices.count - 1 || row < indices[i + 1] {
            index -= indices[i]
            break
        }
    }

    return index
}

func getHeaderIndices() -> [Int] {
    var index = 0
    var indices: [Int] = []

    for section in self.sections {
        indices.append(index)
        index += section.items.count + 1
    }

    return indices
   }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you've mistakenly used a dictionary, which has no order. You need an array. It could be an array of one-item dictionaries, or even of tuples:

```
let arr : [(String, [String])] = ...
```

Even better, make a custom struct and use an array of that:

```
struct Model {
    let section : String
    let rows : [String]
}
```

Now your data is a `[Model]`.